# Read file up to a character

Tags: python

I am writing a script to process X12 EDI files, which I would like to iterate line-by-line. The files are composed of a sequence of distinct records, each terminated by a special character (e.g. `~`, but see below). The files may be large (>100 MB), so I do not want to read the whole thing in and split it. The records are not newline-separated; reading in the first line would probably read the whole file. The files are all-ASCII.

Python clearly provides for reading a file up to a certain character, provided that that character is a newline. I would like to do the same thing with an arbitrary character. I presume that reading by line is implemented via buffering. I could implement my own buffered reader, but I would rather avoid the extra code and the overhead if there is a better solution.

Note: I've seen a few similar questions, but they all seemed to conclude that one should read the file in by the line, presuming that the lines would be a reasonable size. In this case, the whole file will probably be one line.

Edit: The segment terminator character is whatever the 106th byte of the file is. It is not known before the script is invoked.

Comment: Maybe use `.read(some_reasonable_number)` on the file pointer and search through the result until you find your `~`, and if you do, `.seek()` backwards?

Comment: I believe you're right about the buffered reader, and unfortunately the `newline` argument in `open` doesn't allow `~`.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to write a dedicated implementation over an io.BytesIO, reading the file in chunks and sending back *line* ended with you particular delimiter ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still far from optimal, but it would be a pure-Python implementation of a very simple buffer:

```
def my_open(filename, char):
    with open(filename) as f:
        old_fb=""
        for file_buffer in iter(lambda: f.read(1024), ''):
            if old_fb:
                file_buffer = old_fb + file_buffer
            pos = file_buffer.find(char)
            while pos != -1 and file_buffer:
                yield file_buffer[:pos]
                file_buffer = file_buffer[pos+1:]
                pos = file_buffer.find(char)
            old_fb = file_buffer
        yield old_fb

# Usage:
for line in my_open("weirdfile", "~"):
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 4):

If there aren't going to be newlines in the file to start with, transform the file before piping it into your Python script, e.g.:

```
tr '~' '\n' < source.txt | my-script.py
```

Then use `readline()`, `readlines()`, or `for line in file_object:` as appropriate.

Comment: And if the program takes the file from the command line, not stdin, at least in bash you can use process substitution: `my-script.py <(tr '~' '\n' < source.txt)`.

Comment: The segment terminator is not known at script invocation time. I have clarified the original question. In addition, this script will be run in a Windows environment I'm not very familiar with, so standard UNIX tools may not be available. Also, wouldn't that process substitution effectively put the entire file contents in a buffer anyway if the python script didn't read it quickly enough?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this

warning: code not optimized

```
class File(object):

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.file = f

    def readline(self, delimiter='~'):
        buffer = ''
        while True:
            b = self.file.read(1)
            buffer += b
            if b:
                if b == delimiter:
                   yield buffer
                   buffer = ''
            else:
               yield buffer
               break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with a custom class. I'd like to make it a subclass of `io.BufferedIO`, but I can't figure out how to access the buffer.

Note that this starts by reading 1 byte, then 2 bytes, then 4 bytes etc. So if you've got GB to read through for a single line, it won't take forever.

```
from io import StringIO, TextIOWrapper

class SplitResult:
    max_chunk_size = 2**24
    
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.buffer = ''
        
    def close(self):
        self.f.close()
        
    def read(self, size=-1):
        if size < 0:
            return self.buffer + self.f.read()
        elif size == 0:
            return ''
        elif size <= len(self.buffer):
            ret = self.buffer[:size]
            self.buffer = self.buffer[size:]
            return ret
        else: # size > len(self.buffer)
            ret = self.buffer
            self.buffer = ''
            return ret + self.f.read(size - len(ret))
        
    # read the file until you hit string s or EOF
    # return up to that, excluding that
    def read_until(self, s=FILE_SEP):
    
        chunks = [self.buffer]
        chunk_size = 1
        while s not in chunks[-1]:
            chunks.append(self.f.read(chunk_size))
            chunk_size = min(chunk_size*2, self.max_chunk_size)
            if chunks[-1] == '':
                # end of file
                break
            
        result, _, self.buffer = ''.join(chunks).partition(s)
        
        return result
        
s = SplitResult(StringIO("123~456~789"))

assert s.read_until('~') == '123'
assert s.read_until('~') == '456'
assert s.read_until('~') == '789'
```